# Exit a fork but return to parent

Tags: perl, fork

I am having an issue with my first attempt at using `fork`.

The script seems to run fine until I need it to exit the fork and return to the main script.

Instead it exits the script entirely.

```
my @files = glob( "./input/<Input subnets>.txt" ) or die "Can't open HostInventory$!";     # Open the Host Inventory csv files for parsing

foreach my $file ( @files ) {

    open (CONFIG, '<', $file) or die "Can't <Input subnets>.txt$!";
    my @lines = <CONFIG>;
    chomp (@lines);

    $m = scalar @lines / 10;
    for ( $m ) {
        s/\..*//g
    };

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @lines; $i += $m ) {

        # take a slice of elements from @files
        my @lines4 = @lines[$i .. $i + $m];

        if ( fork() == 0 ) {

            for my $n ( @lines4 ) {
                system("Nmap -dns-servers <IP of DNS server> -sn -v $n -oX ./input/ip360_DNS/ip360_DNS$n.xml --send-eth --reason");
            }

            exit;  
        }
    }

    wait for 0 .. @lines/$m;
}
```

At this point it should continue in the parent script and open a subroutine that parses the output of the scan.  Instead it exits the script completely.

What am I doing wrong?

-=-=-=-=Update-=-=-=-=
I tried the Parallel::ForkManager example below. When run as a standalone process it work perfectly. I am running the code inside of a subroutine though and when I try that, the Perl interpreter crashes. Suggestions?

```
#1/usr/bin/perl -w

use Parallel::ForkManager;
use strict;                                             # Best Practice
use warnings;                                           # Best Practice
use Getopt::Long;                                       # Add the ability to use command line options

 if (!@ARGV) {
    &help;
    exit 1
}

GetOptions(
    full =>                 \&full,
    temp =>                 \&temp,
);

                #######################################################################
                #######################################################################
                #                                                                     #
                #                      Call each function                             #
                #                                                                     #
                #######################################################################
                #######################################################################

sub temp {
    &speak;
    &simple;
    &speak2;
    exit;
}

sub full {
    &speak;
    &simple;
    &speak2;
    exit;
}   

sub speak {
    print "This is where I wait for 2 seconds\n";
    sleep (2);
}

my $process = $$;
print "$process\n";

sub simple {

    my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(10);
    $pm->run_on_finish(
    sub { $process;
        print "** PID $process\n";
        }
    );

    my @files = glob( "./ping.txt" ) or die "Can't open CMS HostInventory$!";     # Open the CMS Host Inventory csv files for parsing
    foreach my $file (@files){
        open (CONFIG, '<', $file) or die "Can't ip360_DNS File$!";
        my @lines = <CONFIG>;
        chomp (@lines);

        foreach my $n (@lines) {
            # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
            my $pid = $pm->start and next; 

            # ... do some work with $data in the child process ...
            system("ping $n >> ./input/$n.txt");

        }
        $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
    }
}

sub speak2 {
    print "In new subroutine\n";
}
```

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager will make your life a bit easier.

Comment: `fork()` creates a second process that is an exact copy of the original.  The original continues to run, as well as the copy.  There is no "return" from a forked process.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, They're not using the word "return" literally. They want the parent to wait for the children to complete, then proceed with some other code.

Comment: To supplement what @Jim_Garrison said, you want to "use threads; threads->create(\&worker_fxn);" instead of fork() - google whats the difference between perl threads vs forking.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your script doesn't "exit completely". It does wait for the children to finish. Or at least some of them. Your calculations are a little off.

---

You're skipping the last elements.

```
$m = scalar @lines / 10;
for ($m) {s/\..*//g};
```

is equivalent to

```
use POSIX qw( floor );

my $m = floor(@lines / 10);
```

but it should be

```
use POSIX qw( ceil );

my $m = ceil(@lines / 10);
```

---

You're performing the boundary elements twice.

```
my @lines4 = @lines[$i .. $i + $m];
```

should be

```
my @lines4 = @lines[$i .. $i + $m - 1];
```

---

```
wait for 0 .. @lines/$m;
```

should be

```
use POSIX qw( ceil );

wait for 1 .. ceil(@lines/$m);
```

or just

```
1 while wait > 0;
```

---

Easier to use [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager).

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);  # Max number of children at a time.

$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit, $id, $signaled, $dumped, $data) = @_;
   my ($config_qfn, $target) = @$id;
   ...
});

for my $config_qfn (glob(...)) {
    open(my $config_fh, '<', $config_qfn)
       or die("Can't open \"$config_qfn\": $!\n");

    chomp( my @targets = <$config_fh> );

    for my $target (@targets) {
        my $pid = $pm->start([$config_qfn, $target])
           and next;

        exec(...)
           or die("exec: $!");
    }
}

$pm->wait_all_children();
```

By the way, you may have noticed I stopped doing things in batches. This allowed me to use `exec` instead of `system`, which reduces the number of forks by one for each batch, making it more efficient to not use batches.

Comment: I tried the Parallel::ForkManager example above.  When run as a standalone process it work perfectly.  I am running the code inside of a subroutine though and when I try that, the Perl interpreter crashes.  Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows.

Comment: Neither `fork` nor `exec` exist on Windows. It's superficially emulated using threads, but it's really not the same thing. You'd do best to avoid `fork`! I'd use a thread-based worker pool.